# Casting an array of strings to an array of integers

Tags: postgresql

How can I cast an array of string into an array of integers?

Below is my array

```
["6", "5"]
```

I want convert into int array

```
[6, 5]
```

Comment: Do you have a simple postgres array or a JSON array? That looks like a JSON array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=04538a7e493d5d032ce5d5e0f313da68)

```
SELECT
    array_agg(elems::int)
FROM unnest(ARRAY['5', '6']) as elems
```

1. Expand the array into one record per element
2. Reaggregate cast integer values

To ensure the original order, you need to add `WITH ORDINALITY`, which adds an index to the original array:

```
SELECT
    array_agg(elems.value::int ORDER BY elems.index)
FROM unnest(ARRAY['5', '6']) WITH ORDINALITY as elems(value, index)
```

If you have a JSON array instead, the algorithm is the same, only the used functions have different names:

```
SELECT
    json_agg(elems.value::int ORDER BY elems.index)
FROM json_array_elements_text('["5", "6"]'::json) WITH ORDINALITY as elems(value, index)
```

---

**EDIT**: According to comment:

> this is my query. SELECT data->>'pid' FROM user_data where
> data->>'pid' is not null How can I update pid to array of integers ?

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=df029a6350bf96b187060d4d1b7fa226)

You have to expand and reaggregate nonetheless:

```
SELECT 
    json_agg(elems::int)                              -- 2
FROM user_data,
    json_array_elements_text(data -> 'pid') as elems  -- 1
WHERE data->>'pid' IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: this is my query.
SELECT data->>'pid' FROM user_data where data->>'pid' is not null
How can I update pid to array of integers ?

Comment: Please add such information into your **questions**. Add some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: How can I update all pid to array of integer with update statement ?

Comment: That's the correct UPDATE. You need to use jsonb_set(): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7d88fa1428d47a6aea7b20a8019d1762

Answer (score 0):

You can’t “cast”, but you can get something very close to a cast:

```
array(select unnest(myArray)::int)
```

As a testable query:

```
select array(select unnest(array['5', '6'])::int)
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/70884).

When applying to a column of a selected table:

```
select
    array(select unnest(myArrayCol)::int)
from myTable
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ae6b5/1).

This syntax preserves order.